# NextJs Link causes Error: Loading initial props cancelled

Tags: javascript, next.js, next.js13

I have nextjs 13 app and I have navbar component with some Nextjs links. **After pressing  the link and the page starts loading if you click the same link fast some times it throws this error:** `Error: Loading initial props cancelled`.

What I did:

```
//navbar.ts
const [loadingPath, setLoadingPath] = useState()
useEffect(() => {
    Router.events.on('routeChangeComplete', () => setLoadingPath(undefined))
}, [])

const onClickExample= (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    setLoadingPath('/example')
    if (loadingPath === '/example' || router.asPath === '/example') return
    router.push('/example')
}
//jsx
<Link href="/example" onClick={onClickExample}>Go to Example</Link > // Nextjs Link
```

**There are some discussians like this [github issue](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/40554). It happens on Nextjs 12 too according comments around the net.**

*This is common user behavior and it's weird to throws such errors.*

**How do you handle it? Any elegant solution?**

Comment: i'm getting this error today with Next  latest (13 something). i'm just going to try to move it server side. i also just posted on the github issue you shared with more detail of how im getting the error

Comment: im sure as hell not putting a settimeout on my app for that. ill switch to vite before i do that